# Parsing date in CST format is one day behind in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to parse UTC date into CST but it always return one day behind

```
String date = "2015-01-01T00:00:00";
String sourceFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
String targetFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(sourceFormat);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date strDate = new Date();

    try {
        strDate = sdf.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(targetFormat);
    sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); // Phone is set to GMT - 6 Hours America
    return sdf2.format(strDate);
```

this returns **"12/31/2014"** which is one date behind

This returns **"2014-12-31T18:00:00"** if i use my sourceFormat as my target format

Comment: Try without time zone(s).

Comment: '"12/31/2014" which is one date behind'. I would say that's a day before. Or earlier.